# How to interpret asymptotic standard error of Somers' D

Tags: statistical-significance, standard-error, somers-d

I see SAS provide asymptotic standard error of Somers' D. My question is how to interpret it and when should I used it for the statistical testing for Somers' D? Now I only have one out of time validation sample. Can I use the Somers' D asymptotic standard error to test if the Somers' D between the training sample and the validation sample is significantly different? If yes, what test should I use.